# Merge two columns if their values are the same in a third column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], 
                   'B': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                   'C': ['d', 'd', 'e', 'e'],
                   'D': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],})
```

I want to merge the values of all columns where the values in A are unique.

```
ouput = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], 
                     'BC': ['bd', 'bd', 'ce', 'ce'],
                      'D': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],})
```

It would be best to have a solution that works independently of column names B, C (perhaps there are also more columns with this "redundant information"). The column name of A is known.

Given the case that my initial dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], 
                   'B': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                   'C': ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e'],
                   'D': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],})
```

the desired output is the initial df (no change):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], 
                   'B': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                   'C': ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e'],
                   'D': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],})
```

Many thanks!

Full solution (thanks to Robby the Belgian):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
                   'B': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                   'C': ['d', 'd', 'e', 'e'],
                   'D': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x']})

print(df)

def is_redundant(df, A, B):
    #remove column a
    A=A
    B=B
    if len(df.groupby(f'{A}')) == len(df.groupby([f'{A}', f'{B}'])):

        return True
    else:
        return False

def drop_redundant(df, redundant_groups):
    list=redundant_groups
    for i in list:
        if len(df.groupby(f'{i[0]}')) == len(df.groupby([f'{i[0]}', f'{i[1]}'])):
            df[f'{i[0]}' + f'{i[1]}'] = df[[f'{i[0]}', f'{i[1]}']].sum(axis=1)
            df.drop([f'{i[0]}', f'{i[1]}'], axis=1, inplace=True)
            return(df)
        else:
            return(df)

cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'A']
redundant_groups = []
idx_left = 0
while idx_left < len(cols)-1:
    new_group = []
    idx_right = idx_left+1
    while idx_right < len(cols):
        if is_redundant(df, cols[idx_left], cols[idx_right]):
            new_group.append(cols.pop(idx_right))
        else:
            idx_right += 1
    if new_group:
        redundant_groups.append(new_group + [cols[idx_left]])
    idx_left += 1

print(redundant_groups)

drop_redundant(df, redundant_groups)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  A  B  C  D
0  x1  b  d  x
1  x2  b  d  y
2  x3  c  e  y
3  x4  c  e  x
[['C', 'B']]
    A  D  CB
0  x1  x  db
1  x2  y  db
2  x3  y  ec
3  x4  x  ec
[Finished in 0.837s]
```

Comment: where is your dataframe ? I saw list only

Comment: Also those lists are invalid, please spend some time and create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , you can take help from this link [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your question

Comment: what is the output if 3rd row is `x3 c d y`?

Comment: @deadshot in that case, no change is desired, I updated my initial post. Thank you.

Comment: @solaris i mean 3rd row in dataframe not 3rd key in the dictionary `pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'], 'B': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'C': ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e'],'D': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],})`

Comment: @deadshot Sorry, misunderstood you. Updated again!

Comment: do you want to combine columns if all the rows of that columns are equal?

Comment: @deadshot Equal in terms of their values relative to the values in column A.

Comment: how `x1 b d x` relatively equal to `x2 b d y` can you explain how you are selecting the columns to combine with an example

Comment: Sorry, confusion over columns and rows again. B and C are somehow redundant as their values point to the same values in column A.

Comment: @BEN_YO thank you, created proper pandas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare whether columns `'B'` and `'C'` are "redundant":

```
len(df.groupby('B')) == len(df.groupby(['B', 'C'])
```

This checks whether adding `'C'` to the grouping labels requires us to add more groups, compared to only grouping by `'B'`.

You can then easily run this on all pairs of labels in `df.columns` (making sure to not include `'A'`).

If you find that two columns have redundant information, you can use:

```
df['B' + 'C'] = df[['B', 'C']].sum(axis=1)
df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

to replace them with the combined information.

If you want to use this in a double loop (checking all pairs of columns), you'll have to be careful, since you might have 3 columns that all contain the same information (say, B, C, and F), and after dealing with B and C you would try to compare B and F -- but column B does no longer exist.

To deal with this, I might try first constructing a list of all pairs that are redundant. Let's assume we have a "`is_redundant(df, c1, c2)`" function (which uses the above line to compare).

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'A']
redundant_groups = []
idx_left = 0
while idx_left < len(cols)-1:
    new_group = []
    idx_right = idx_left+1
    while idx_right < len(cols):    
        if is_redundant(df, cols[idx_left], cols[idx_right]):
            new_group.append(cols.pop(idx_right))
        else:
            idx_right += 1
    if new_group:
        redundant_groups.append(new_group + [cols[idx_left]])
    idx_left += 1
```

This creates groups of columns that are all mutually redundant.

After that, you can easily modify the above combination code to deal with multiple columns at once.

Comment: Good thinking, thank you very much! I updated the initial post with the full solution.